# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized in WCF hosted in Windows Service

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which is hosted in Windows Service and windows service is running with "Local System Account".  Service is trying to download a file from SharePoint server and failed with error:

**System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)**

Similar setup is working in another machine and service is able to communicate with Sharepoint site but not in my server. I have tried this setup in another machine but same error except one machine.

What kind of permissions are required to communicate with SharePoint? Also, how can I check what are the credential passed during request?

Comment: You can use tools like Fiddler to monitor your request and response over the network. Have you made sure that the local System Account has permissions to access a resource on the sharepoint server as the windows service runs under the context of local system account user

Comment: Were you able to find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If certificates are involved here, see if this is a certificate issue. Use the [MMC snap-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967.aspx) and compare the certs on the working and non-working machines.